# Windows kernel mini redirector: Handle |FileNormalizedNameInformation| like |FileNameInformation|?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, windows-kernel

We're working on a Windows minirdr-based NFSv4 driver.

Since NFSv4 has no concept of "short filenames", can |FileNormalizedNameInformation| be handled like |FileNameInformation| (see https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/main/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c) ?

Are there any other differences ?

Comment: can. it also is optional and can simply return `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`. differense [FileNormalizedNameInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/20bcadba-808c-4880-b757-4af93e41edf6) vs [FileNameInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/cb30e415-54c5-4483-a346-822ea90e1e89)